# PlayJson update on element of array does not work

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have a json

```
val js =  Json.obj("val" -> Json.arr(Json.obj("a" -> Json.arr(1))))
```

And i want update it

```
Json.obj("val" -> Json.arr(Json.obj("a" -> Json.arr(1))))
  .transform((__ \\ "val") (0).json.update(__.read[JsArray].map { jsVal => println(jsVal); jsVal }))
```

My update message do not print nothing. and even do not call in debug.
But `pick` methods find this element.

```
js.transform((__ \\ "val")(0).json.pick)
```

return `JsSuccess({"a":[1]},//val(0))`
I can't understand why.
Can some one help me how to update exact element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is not called because read[JsArray] actually returns JsError:

```
val js = Json.obj("val" -> Json.arr(Json.obj("a" -> Json.arr(1))))
val result1 = js.transform((__ \\ "val") (0).json.update(Reads.of[JsArray]))
println(result1)
// JsError(List((//val(0),List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray())))))
```

You can print the value causing it in this way:

```
val result2 = js.transform((__ \\ "val")(0).json.update(
  Reads(v => { println(v); v.validate[JsArray] })
))
println(result2) 
// {"a":[1]} - same value as in pick!
// JsError(List((//val(0),List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray()))))
```

Now we know it's an object so let's try to touch it

```
val result3 = js.transform((__ \\ "val")(0).json.update(Reads.of[JsObject]))
println(result3)
// java.lang.RuntimeException: expected KeyPathNode
```

Let's check implementation of update:
https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/2.6.9/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsConstraints.scala#L85-L94

It basically:

1. reads (with optional transformation) a value identified by path from root object
2. creates an object with only those path and value
3. applies JsObject.deepMerge to the root object and the value-holding one

Method JsPath.createObj used in 2) can handle paths specified by keys only, but not by indices. So it seems it's impossible to modify elements of nested arrays in play-json, at least out of the box.

Meanwhile in circe land:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wRLs7O72ScyOmcMyiTU5uw